# How does using Flip Flops between transmission links increase the maximum clock speed?

Tags: frequency, delay, transmission

I am learning about things such as propagation delay and Transmission delays. About how they limit the maximum Clock speed in a given system (where all the chips use the same clock line).

I can't post images as yet but I'll try my best:

**Initial circuit:**

invClock->MicroProcessor(A) -- (Transmission line with delay) -- Microprocessor(B)

**Improved circuit which *somehow increases maximum allowable clock frequency*:**

invClock->Microproccessor(A) -- FF -- (Transmission line w/ delay) -- invClock->FF -- Microprocessor (B)

The clock is also transmitted in an indentical transmission line, with the same delay.

How does this work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVabmP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you give any context where you read this?

Comment: I'm studying this right now, and this came up in a problem sheet. It is supposed to be a simplistic design to provide an introduction to the topic of calculating maximum frequency.

Comment: As drawn the output from processor A goes to an input to processor B with the clock feeding both processors synchronously. If there is a 23nS max (output to input)delay the clock must not change in this time otherwise the data will be lost. So the clock period needs to be greater than 23 nS. or to put it another way the clock frequency can be no faster than about 43.5 MHz. (f = 1/T) Delaying the clock pulse allows the data and clock to arrive at the same time allowing the clock frequency to be increased.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing on-chip propagation delay with transmission delay.

*Within a microprocessor*, the maximum clock speed is limited by the longest propagation delay through the logic between one flip-flop and another. Inserting an intermediate flop and "pipelining" the design allows the increase of clock speed. The wiring is generally so short that it's not considered as a transmission line.

On a board, there's no sensible advantage to inserting discrete flip-flops.

Comment: What do you mean by pipelining the design?

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm very sure I'm talking about the delay outside the chip. The transmission lines connecting the two microprocessors are between two separate boards. I'll try to create a diagram using the circuit diagram creating tool to explain.

Comment: However, there is a propagation delay within the two microprocessors

Answer (score 0):

It basically works by saving the intermediate result of a calculation, so it can take two clock cycles to do the calculation instead of one.

Let's say you have four increment blocks strung together, like this:

```
inc -> inc -> inc -> inc
```

If each one takes 1 ns to complete, your clock period must be greater than 4 ns.  Now insert a flip-flop in the middle, like this:

```
inc -> inc -> ff -> inc -> inc
```

Now your clock period can be reduced to 2 ns, because the result only has to propagate to the flip flop before the next clock hits.  Then on the second clock cycle it goes the rest of the way.

Actually, you also add the setup time of the flip flop, so your total propagation time for the inc-by-four is higher, but your clock can be faster, which might be useful for other parts of your circuit.

Comment: So, what you are saying is unrelated to the transmission delay in the diagram I have shown in the post?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a logic circuit or a transmission line causing the delay.  If you put a flip flop in the middle of the transmission line it will have the same effect.